# Fix Ubuntu 16.04 issue with Gigabyte GA-AB350 motherboard and AMD Ryzen CPU

Tags: kernel, cpu, motherboard

I recently bought a fully new PC with Gigabyte GA-AB350-GAMING 3 and AMD Ryzen 5 1500X 3.5GHZ.

My intent was to have dual boot with Win10 for games and Ubuntu for work. So, I installed Win10 - a smooth process - and then proceeded to install Ubuntu. And all hell broke loose.

It all began with IRQ messages:

> ⁠⁠⁠Unexpected irq trap at vector 07

I [googled around](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2354925&page=2&s=c09c58b673f3ae59220ad82ebbf80ef1) and noticed that precisely this motherboard had issues with ubuntu (or is it the other way around?) and that there was a workaround using kernel parameter acpi=off. That worked, i got to install it, but now it runs on only one core and the system locks up during shutdown (i have to press the power button to power it off).

By the way, currently I'm on

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I read about it being an issue with the kernel, that you needed at least 4.10 for the motherboard to work, so I installed Ukuu and got myself the latest stable kernel

> $ uname -a
>
> Linux funkybox 4.12.10-041210-generic #201708300614 SMP Wed Aug 30 10:16:40 TC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

However, it still shows a single CPU core

my cat /proc/cpuinfo results: https://pastebin.com/E5fhFDLj

I also notice the lack of CPU cores because sometimes the system will slow down even more than my previous several-years-old PC with tasks as simple as streaming.

If the motherboard windows app does what I think, the BIOS should be up-to-date, since I tend to pay attention to the notifications. I wish there was something of that kind for linux, a native app to update/manage BIOS.
UPDATE: I just updated BIOS from F7 to F8, so now it IS up-to-date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Graphics card?...

Comment: Geforce Gtx 1060. Does it have something to do with the "lack" of CPU cores? 0o

Comment: No, but it explains why you and the UF thread you quoted had been approaching it the wrong way. Instead of disabling ACPI features (which causes it to use only one core) the boot parameter you need is `nomodeset` (forces generic VESA graphics instead of relying on the default open source `nouveau`driver) to boot the live session, install and then again to boot the installed OS and install the recommended Nvidia drivers. Only then you can remove `nomodeset` from Grub.

Comment: Ok, I just changed the parameters in grub and now I do see my 4 (+ 4 from HT) CPU cores. Thanks! If you could put it as an answer so you get the credit for closing the question it'd be great! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So credits go to @MichaelBay

- Set the kernel parameter `acpi=nomodeset` so you can boot the live session and install the OS
- Boot the installed OS and install Nvidia drivers
- Remove `nomodeset` from Grub

With that you should be set.