# Only 1 core of CPU is recognized with acpi=off (Windows11+Ubuntu Dualboot)

Tags: 22.04, intel, cpu, lts, acpi

I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installed on a DAIV X7. (Windows11 + Ubuntu Dualboot)

This PC could not be installed as it was, and when I searched it, I found a way to add `acpi=off` to the Kernel parameter in GRUB. As a result, Ubuntu was installed. but
CPU is supposed to have at least 8 cores, but the system monitor indicates only one core.
(And I have not had this problem with Windows11.)

### System Information

**PC Model:** DAIV X7 (Not homemade)
**PC manufacturer:** Mouse Computer
**Motherboard:** X299-S01A (Manufacturer's Original Motherboard)
**CPU:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900X CPU @ 3.70GHz
**Graphic board:** NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 (UPDATE 12/11/2022)
**Ubuntu Version:** 22.04.1
**BIOS:** MSI BIOS
**BIOS Ver:** E7A941MO.A07

### What I tried

1. [How to fix Ubuntu showing only one core?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358402/how-to-fix-ubuntu-showing-only-one-core) --> Not working on intel
2. Change Ubuntu Version to 20.04.5 --> Nothing has changed
3. Install CUDA and Bumblebee --> Nothing has changed (Update 12/4/2022)
4. Added "nr_cpus=10" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in /etc/default/grub and run `grub-mkconfig`. --> Nothing has changed (Update 12/4/2022)
5. Restore Secure Boot and Fast Boot in BIOS to default(Enable) --> Nothing has changed (Update 12/9/2022)
6. Use acpi=noirs instead of acpi=off --> Stops with "Booting a command list".
7. Use nomodeset instead of acpi=off --> Stops with "Booting a command list".
8. Use acpi=noirq instead of acpi=off --> Stops with "Booting a command list". (UPDATE 12/15/2022)
9. Use noapic, irqpoll instead of acpi=off --> Stops with blank screen (UPDATE 12/15/2022)
10. Use nolapic instead of acpi=off --> Booted. but the problem persists... (UPDATE 12/20/2022)

---

`cat /proc/cpuinfo` Output:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 85
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900X CPU @ 3.70GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x5003302
cpu MHz     : 3985.867
cache size  : 19712 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp_pkg_req avx512_vnni md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer posted_intr invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority apicv tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest vapic_reg vid ple ept_mode_based_exec tsc_scaling
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs taa itlb_multihit mmio_stale_data
bogomips    : 7399.70
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Are there any other options in your GRUB startup options? 22.04 supports that generation of Intel processor just fine 

Comment: Thanks for reply. options is only a "acpi=off quiet splash"

Comment: settings in BIOS?

Comment: BIOS is a MSI BIOS.
I disabled Secure Boot and Fast Boot in BIOS Settings.

Comment: have you check for any firmware/BIOS updates for your machine? Also other acpi options might be available which are less drastic -- see some kernel parameter list.  See  https://askubuntu.com/questions/951630/fix-ubuntu-16-04-issue-with-gigabyte-ga-ab350-motherboard-and-amd-ryzen-cpu

Comment: thank you for your reply. I added nomodeset by referring to the link destination, but it stops with "Booting a command list".

Comment: Check for missing firmware with sudo dmesg |grep -i firm   and see if any failed to load or is missing.  Again, did you check with the vendor for any firmware updates?  I've see this sort of problem (need acpi=off, but then cpus=1) fixed with a firmware update, then acpi was no longer required just to boot.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I ran the command, then returned: `[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST: CPU0: -4480486116438 force to 0`. and There is no mention of firmware update on the manufacturer's official website, so it seems that there is probably no firmware update.

Comment: Have you tried booting with `acpi_osi=\"Windows 2015\"` instead of turning acpi off? The BIOS may expect a specific string to work. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/acpi/winacpi-osi for all possible values where it says "OSI strings for Windows operating systems".

Answer (score 2):

This is something to do with the BIOS... Possibilities:

1. You are using a processor the mainboard is pin compatible with, but the BIOS/Chipset are not. (You haven't posted enough information here for me to tell. Make/Model would help.) Just because it can fit in the socket doesn't mean it will work. The chipset, mainboard, and BIOS have to support it explicitly.
2. They are compatible but you haven't installed the latest BIOS revision. This would be the easiest to fix. You just have to go download that and install it to your computer.
3. The cores are disabled inside the bios itself. Many higher end bios allow you to selectively disable the cores.

I'd check #3 first, because you don't have to alter the computer or go fishing through the web to figure that one out. After that, I'd go into the updating the bios to the latest release, because again no reading. Figuring out whether the board supports the chip specifically can often be an arduous task unless you can see in the documents/revisions of the BIOS that your processor is explicitly listed.

Take all the silly command line options out of the grub, run update-grub, and start along this other line. Linux will find whatever the BIO reports, but if it doesn't it is all the BIOS causing this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I am trying to upgrade the BIOS as I could not find any setting in the BIOS that would turn the CPU core on or off.

I am currently trying to find out what type of motherboard this PC has in order to update the BIOS.

It is listed in the BIOS as X299-S01A, but I could not find that motherboard in my search. Since this PC is a creator computer, I am assuming that the motherboard is a Creator X299. (It matches the "X299").

Comment: @K-Orange It's unlikely you could successfully install the wrong bios. But, generally it's just the make/manufacturer of the main board which you can read right off the board it's written on it in white usually. If this is a machine from a vendor they might have some weird bios, and you will have to download it from the manufacturer of the computer. If the vendor is "Creator" they should have the bios updates. You may have to email them to get them if they're not on their site. (I've had to before, lol.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I don't know the model number of the motherboard, so I contacted the manufacturer's support just to be sure, and they told me that the X299-S01A motherboard, which is proprietary to the manufacturer, is used.
They said that a normal MSI BIOS update is likely to break the PC.
And we found that the BIOS of the PC is up to date.
I forgot to mention in my question that this PC is a Windows 11+Ubuntu dual boot, and it is not happening on Windows 11.

Comment: @K-Orange unfortunately you're probably in the situation that this PC just won't function correctly in Linux. (Not all of them do.) When I started using Linux the only laptop it'd run on was a ThinkPad, and if you weren't using Dell/Compaq/IBM/HP/etc computers no hope in hell that it'd work very well. The reason it's working in Windows is that the motherboard/bios manufacturer put all the right drivers for their weirdness in the Windows Update repository. It's not because the hardware is working correctly. :D Linux follows standards, so as long as the maker does it works. If they don't, nope.